# Emacs still shown in 'Software' program even though it's uninstalled

Tags: 20.04, emacs

[image]

Emacs is still shown even though I've removed and purged it. It's not installed it, the terminal lets me know it's not installed and I can't lauch it, yet that remains. What can be done?

Comment: Very unclear. Please share the output of `dpkg -l | grep emacs` ; `snap list | grep -i emacs`  ; `flatpak list | grep -i emacs` .

Comment: Only the 'dpkg' one returns anything, and it returns: `rc  emacs-common                                1:26.3+1-1ubuntu2                     all          GNU Emacs editor's shared, architecture independent infrastructure
ii  emacsen-common                              3.0.4                                 all          Common facilities for all emacsen`